# How to load an assembly using probing?

Tags: c#, probing

I want to load an assembly from a subfolder named `myFolder`. I created a new directory `C:\App\myFolder` and move the `Test.dll` file to there and used probing in `app.config` like this:

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <probing privatePath="myFolder"/>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Then I tried to load that assembly:

```
Assembly ex = Assembly.Load("Test");
```

But it throws an exception that there is not this assembly in `bin/debug`

Comment: `Assembly.LoadFrom` expects the full path to the assembly, so it won't use the probing path. You should try `Assembly.Load("nameOfYourAssembly")`

Comment: It still doesn't work